# Set woocommerce product price based on dealer location

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to work out if it's possible to have a single site with one set of products but to be able to vary the price of the product based on the location of the dealer.

We want to operate the one website so that the product information is kept up to date and relevant. When a customer comes to the website they will be geolocated or they can select the dealer closest to them. We have a few dealers selling the products in different parts of the country. However, the dealers want to be able to increase or decrease the prices for their location on some products because it costs more for them to get the products shipped to them, etc.

So, what I am looking for is some way to be able to have location based pricing for woocommerce products. Is there something like that built in or can someone recommend a plugin that can help with this?